# Azure devops widget based on json

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dashboard

I am creating a custom widget and having some stastics which is coming from jason data. i am able to create widget and fine. Now i want to automate this process so that as soon as jason file arrives in folder it refreshes the graph in widget. Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do it.

As far as I know , the Dashboards widget uses the `load` and `reload` function to load the widgets.

You can add conditions according to your needs, and then use the `load` or `reload` method in the return function to refresh the widget.

Here is [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops#step-3-javascript---enable-live-preview), you could refer to it.

In addition，the dashboard also has automatic refresh function.

You could select the `Automatically refresh the dashboard every 5 minutes` [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/dashboards?view=azure-devops#rename-delete-and-enable-auto-refresh) in Dashboards settings. Then the widgets will refresh every 5 minutes.

Hope this helps.